# Yii module internationalization

Tags: php, yii, module, internationalization

I need internationalization in my module `admin_test`. I created `"messages"` folder in module's directory and `"en"/"ru"` folders in it. Filled `translation.php` files in them the following way:

```
<?php

return array(
    'test' => 'тест',
);
```

in my templates and views i use messages this way

```
<?=Yii::t('Admin_testModule.translation', 'test')?>
```

But there is no translation in view. I just get label `"test"` instead of its translation. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think that it is duplicate, because author of this question have no problem with internationalization of module, he had problem with submodules.

Comment: I'm trying to do right this way. No result

Comment: I assume you set the language as ru in the config.php?

Comment: instead of Admin_testModule.translation use translation